# Implementing the ICloneable Interface C# (Deep Cloning)

Tags: c#, reference, clone

I was looking at code that implemented the `ICloneable` interface for one of the classes.

The class was as follows:

```
public class TempClass
{
  String[] names;
  String[] values;
}
```

A partial class was created that implemented `TempClass`

```
public partial class TempClass:ICloneable
{
   public Object Clone()
   {
      TempClass cloneClass = new TempClass();
      String[] cloneNames = new String[this.names.Length - 1];
      String[] cloneValues = new String[this.values.Length -1];

      Array.Copy(this.names,cloneNames,this.names.Length);
      Array.Copy(this.values,cloneValues,this.values.Length);

      cloneClass.names = cloneNames;
      cloneValues.values = cloneValues;

      return cloneClass;
   }
}
```

I was wondering if this would be a valid way of doing a deep copy of an object? What raises flags here is the intermediate structures `cloneNames` and `cloneValues` that are used to copy the values of the original object and have the member variables `Names` and Values point to it and then return the object reference that was created in the clone method.

Any feedback on this snippet will be well appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone.aspx) and [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) both create shallow copies (as described in the linked API documentation), but using string arrays clouds the issue a bit because strings are immutable in .NET. When you do this:

```
stringArray[0] = "first value";
stringArray[0] = "second value";
```

The first string instance is replaced by a different one, so it looks like you've made a deep copy (and for string arrays, you might as well have done just that).

To perform a deep copy of an object with arrays of normal reference types, you need to create new instances of the array elements. Say `TempClass` stored an array of [`Cookie`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookie.aspx) objects instead of strings:

```
public Object Clone() {
    TempClass clone = new TempClass();

    clone.cookieArray = new Cookie[this.cookieArray.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < this.cookieArray.Length; i++) {
        Cookie cookie  = this.cookieArray[i];
        clone.cookieArray[i] = new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, cookie.Domain);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answers the question, this isn't a valid "Clone()" implementation. If "this" is a subclass of TempClass which doesn't re-implement "Clone()", the proposed code won't return a valid clone of "this". The resulting value of a "Clone()" must *always* be obtained from a call to "MemberwiseClone()".

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's one problem - you're not creating the new string arrays of the right size. It should be:

```
String[] cloneNames = new String[this.names.Length];
String[] cloneValues = new String[this.values.Length];
```

Or as a simpler solution:

```
String[] cloneNames = (String[]) this.names.Clone();
String[] cloneValues = (String[]) this.values.Clone();
```

Other than that, it should be okay. Could you explain your concern in more detail?

Comment: And on top of that, why not just directly set the member arrays of the cloned object?

Comment: @Jeff: Because that would be a shallow clone; the OP apparently wants a deep clone, so that changing the contents of the original array after the fact won't change the new object's arrays.

Comment: D'oh, my question wasn't clear - I mean, what do the intermediary variables add? Why not `cloneClass.names = (String[] this.names.Clone();`

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I was wondering about that. From a memory model standpoint, I was wondering what were the repercussions of setting the member arrays directly vs. maintaining a reference to an intermediate structure.

Tony - Doesn't Array.Clone() make a shallow copy of the values in the data structure?

Comment: @sc_ray - that's correct. However, using `strings` makes the situation a bit confusing because they're immutable. When you 'modify' the value of a `string` element in an array, you're actually replacing it with a different reference (as with a value type). So an object created with `TempClass.Clone` is not affected by changes to the original - but that's not true in the general case. For example, it would not be true for regular reference types (say, an array of `FileInfo` instances). For what it's worth, `Array.Copy` also performs a shallow copy.

Comment: @Jeff Sternal - Thanks Jeff. So how would we approach this if we had an array of objects instead of the strings?

Comment: @Jeff: The only purpose of the intermediary variables here was to keep the code closer to the original :)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your clone method as follows, otherwise pony is right.

```
public Object Clone()
{
    return new TempClass
    {
        names = this.names == null? null:this.names.ToArray(),
        values = this.values == null? null:this.values.ToArray()
    };
}
```

It may be slightly slower than Clone, but it works.

Comment: Thanks Yuriy. But wouldn't the above given code return a reference to the original array instead of copying the array and its contents to the cloned object?

Comment: No, it would create a new array.